# How to remove Ruby from OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, predix

We have ruby with version **ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]**. We need uninstall ruby and install again. So we tried like this

```
Anshuls-Mac-mini-2:~ pankajthakur$ whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
Anshuls-Mac-mini-2:~ pankajthakur$ rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm: /usr/bin/ruby: Permission denied
```

We need re-install in other location. Please guide to us.

My current MAC os Version 10.11.5 (El Capitan)

Comment: Why do you want want to uninstall Ruby? How did you install Ruby? Do you use an version manager like rbenv or RVM? What is the output of `which ruby`

Comment: @spickermann thanks for reply .We install ruby using RVM.OutPut of Which ruby :-/usr/bin/ruby.
We are working on Prefix invermetal setup.We goto error regards

 sudo gem install cf-uaac --http-proxy http://sjc1intproxy01.crd.ge.com:8080  

After r&d We found ,we need changed location on ruby currently it located in usr/bin

Comment: You seemt o not properly loading RVM so that your RVM-installed rubies are not properly detected. You should fix this instead of messing with the system-Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the same version on one of my computer and I used [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install the latest version and overwrite the old one.

In your terminal run `brew install ruby` to download the latest version and then run `brew link --overwrite ruby` to replace your version of Ruby.

You can also use [`rbenv`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) to install and run different version of Ruby on your computer `brew install rbenv`.

EDIT: I think `rbenv` might be the easiest way to manage your Ruby environment.

Comment: brew link --overwrite ruby no longer works https://nathankleyn.com/2019/01/15/homebrew-system-util-breaking-change/